# Why does product [] return 1?

Tags: haskell

Why does the function `product` in Haskell return `1` if it is given an empty list?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lists form a *monoid* structure, with associative binary operation `++` and neutral element `[]`. That is, we have

```
[] ++ xs = xs = xs ++ []    (xs ++ ys) ++ zs = xs ++ (ys ++ zs)
```

Meanwhile, numbers have lots of monoid structure, but the relevant one here is that where the operation is `*` and the neutral element is `1`.

```
1 * x = x = x * 1           (x * y) * z = x * (y * z)
```

The `product` function is not only a map from lists of numbers to numbers: it's a *monoid homomorphism*, reflecting the list monoid structure in the numerical monoid. Crucially,

```
product (xs ++ ys) = product xs * product ys
```

and

```
product [] = 1
```

In fact, to get the former, we pretty much have the latter forced upon us.

Comment: i.e. `product xs = product (xs ++ []) = product xs * product []` thus it must be `product [] = 1`.

Answer (score 8):

Because that's the identity in the category of multiplication.

To be more practical:

```
product [1,2,3] == 1 * product 2:3:[]
                == 1 * 2 * product 3:[]
                == 1 * 2 * 3 * product []
```

Which in turn allows you to implement it with a simple recursion:

```
product [] = 1
product (x:xs) = x * product xs
```

Comment: @developerbmw you'll find that wearing your maths hat in Haskell is often beneficial.

Answer (score 7):

It's a math thing - you usually define a empty sum to be `0` and an empty product to be `1` because this will fit your usual laws nicely

for example this way you can justify the inductive definition of a product - [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product)

Answer (score 2):

Product is a fold with initial value of 1 so when folding an empty list it just returns the init value, wich is 1.

An example of product implementation to ilustrate it:

```
product :: [Int] -> Int
product lst = foldr (\x y -> x*y) 1 lst
```

Take a look to [fold](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold) to understand properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best explained in [@Bartek Banachewicz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33732587/4543207) but i just would like add the fact that this all boils down to one famous question in math;

> Why is `0!` equal to `1`?

The `Empty` element should not break the recursion, in other words it should behave like an identity element. All in all, in math the recursive definition of factorial is;

> ```
> n! = (n+1)! / (n+1)
> ```

Accordingly, a Haskell beauty

```
factorial :: Int -> Integer
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

works just fine as it is. I mean without a test for `n` being `0` i.e. `[1..0]` yielding `[]`. This might possibly be another question topic.